# One of my half round can't bevel

Tags: modeling, modifiers

My mesh has one of half round that can't bevel.

I don't know how to fix it

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, probably the faces are overlapping so it doesn't let you bevel, but maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: all ready upload bro . [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=AdYO4PRQ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/AdYO4PRQ/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have double vertices, as moonboots assumed right.

Just select all vertices in "vertex select" mode -> M -> merge by distance.

Then you will get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much